# How to find occurances of numbers in table columns?

Tags: javascript, html-table, find-occurrences

How do I find the numbers from specific columns in a table with the highest occurances and display them in the corresponding cells of another table based on the 10 most occuring numbers?

https://jsfiddle.net/5feak8j0/2/

```
var col1Array = new Array();
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#stats tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function(i){
col1Array.push($(this).text());
});
alert(col1Array);
});
```

This just makes an alert with the number with the highest occurrance in each column. But I also need the 2nd most, 3rd most, 4th most ect.. occurring number of each column and have the numbers displayed in the corresponding cell of the table above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could probably be the shortest and fool-proof solution:

```
var $input = $('table:last'),
    $output = $('table:first');

$('th', $input).each(function(i) {
    var stat = {};

    $('td:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')', $input).each(function() {
        var num = +$.text(this);
        stat[num] = stat[num] ? stat[num] + 1 : 1;
    });

    $('td:nth-child(' + (i+2) + ')', $output).text(function() {
        var mn = '-', mc = 0;
        $.each(stat, function(num, count) {
            if (mc < count) {
                mc = count;
                mn = num;
            }
        });
        delete stat[mn];
        return mn;
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/5feak8j0/36/

---

```js
var $input = $('table:last'),
    $output = $('table:first');

$('th', $input).each(function(i) {
    var stat = {};
    
    $('td:nth-child(' + (i+1) + ')', $input).each(function() {
        var num = +$.text(this);
        stat[num] = stat[num] ? stat[num] + 1 : 1;
    });
    
    $('td:nth-child(' + (i+2) + ')', $output).text(function() {
        var mn = '-', mc = 0;
        $.each(stat, function(num, count) {
            if (mc < count) {
                mc = count;
                mn = num;
            }
        });
        delete stat[mn];
        return mn;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
table {
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 5%;
    border: solid 1px black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Mode</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;1</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;2</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;3</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;4</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>The Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>2nd Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>3rd Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>4th Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>5th Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>6th Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>7th Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>8th Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>9th Most Occurring Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><b>10th&nbsp;Most&nbsp;Occurring&nbsp;Numbers</b>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Column&nbsp;1</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;2</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;3</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;4</th>
        <th>Column&nbsp;5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>47</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>46</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>44</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>49</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>36</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>38</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>35</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can do this.  To make this easier on you, you can use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs).  A couple of chained methods in lodash would probably solve this for you.  This is actually a good problem to practice your js skills in without using lodash.  I suggest you try to come up with solutions before asking here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/5feak8j0/35/). It is not done fully yet but I have done it so that now can see the `col1Array` containing all data for each column with their number and how many times in occurrence.

Now you can use that array `col1Array` and sort it as per max value and then display in your table.

Hope this will helps you.

**HTML**

```
<table border="1" align="center" id="display">
<tr>
<th>Mode</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;1</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;2</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;3</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;4</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>The Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>2nd Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>3rd Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>4th Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>5th Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>6th Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>7th Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>8th Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>9th Most Occurring Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>10th&nbsp;Most&nbsp;Occurring&nbsp;Numbers</b></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br><br>

<table border="1" align="center" id="stats">
<tr>
<th>Column&nbsp;1</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;2</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;3</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;4</th>
<th>Column&nbsp;5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>37</td>
<td>46</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>7</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>26</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>36</td>
<td>38</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>32</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>41</td>
<td>45</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>40</td>
<td>45</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>29</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>35</td>
<td>41</td>
<td>45</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>15</td>
<td>21</td>
<td>38</td>
<td>39</td>
<td>47</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>43</td>
<td>44</td>
<td>46</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>11</td>
<td>26</td>
<td>32</td>
<td>41</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>11</td>
<td>28</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>37</td>
<td>38</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>36</td>
<td>44</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>17</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>42</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>16</td>
<td>47</td>
<td>49</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>19</td>
<td>33</td>
<td>36</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>33</td>
<td>38</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>8</td>
<td>12</td>
<td>27</td>
<td>31</td>
<td>37</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>6</td>
<td>9</td>
<td>13</td>
<td>14</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>9</td>
<td>22</td>
<td>23</td>
<td>34</td>
<td>35</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>12</td>
<td>15</td>
<td>18</td>
<td>24</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
var col1Array = new Array();
$(document).ready(function () {
    var totalNoOfColumns = $('#stats tr:first').find('th').length;
    for(var i=1;i<=totalNoOfColumns;i++) {
        col1Array[i] = [];
        var tempArray = [];
        $('#stats tr td:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function (i) {
            tempArray[$(this).text()] = (tempArray[$(this).text()]) ? parseInt(tempArray[$(this).text()]) + 1 : 1;
        });
        col1Array[i] = tempArray;
    }
   console.log(col1Array);
});
```

Hope this will helps you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using `sort()`.

```js
var col1Array = [];
// getting counts of values of each column
$('#stats tr td').each(function(i) {
  var ind = $(this).index(),
    pind = $(this).parent().index(),
    num = $(this).text();
  if (pind == 1) {
    col1Array[ind] = {};
  }
  col1Array[ind][num] = col1Array[ind].hasOwnProperty(num) ? col1Array[ind][num] + 1 : 1;
});

var sorted = [];

// soting value based on count
for (var v in col1Array) {
  v = col1Array[v];
  sorted.push(Object.keys(v).sort(function(a, b) {
    if (v[a] < v[b]) return 1;
    if (v[a] > v[b]) return -1;
    return 0;
  }));
}
console.log(sorted);

// updating value to table using sorted array
$('#res tr td').each(function() {
  var ind = $(this).index(),
    pind = $(this).parent().index();
  if (pind > 0 && ind > 0) {
    $(this).text(sorted[ind - 1][pind - 1]);
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  position: relative;
  top: 5%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 5%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" align="center" id=res>
  <tr>
    <th>Mode</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;1</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;2</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;3</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;4</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>The Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>2nd Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>3rd Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>4th Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>5th Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>6th Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>7th Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>8th Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>9th Most Occurring Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>10th&nbsp;Most&nbsp;Occurring&nbsp;Numbers</b>

    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<table id=stats border="1" align="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Column&nbsp;1</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;2</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;3</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;4</th>
    <th>Column&nbsp;5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>46</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>26</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>32</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>40</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>29</td>
    <td>30</td>
    <td>35</td>
    <td>41</td>
    <td>45</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>21</td>
    <td>38</td>
    <td>39</td>
    <td>47</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>43</td>
    <td>44</td>
    <td>46</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>26</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>41</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>37</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>36</td>
    <td>44</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>42</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>16</td>
    <td>47</td>
    <td>49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>36</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>38</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>37</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>23</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>35</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>18</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```